# AngularJS Routes with Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, angularjs

I'm trying to use angularjs routing within a Rails application but I'm having some difficulty. I've split up my page into partials (called _events.html.erb, _categories.html.erb, and _times.html.erb) and I'm set up my routing in my js file like so:

```
myApp.config(['$routeProvider',
    function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
            when('/meetups/new/categories', {
                templateUrl: '??',
                controller: 'MeetupDataCtrl'
            }).
            when('/meetups/new/times', {
                templateUrl: '??',
                controller: 'MeetupDataCtrl'
            }).
            when('/meetups/new/events', {
                templateUrl: '??',
                controller: 'MeetupDataCtrl'
            }).
            otherwise({
                redirectTo: '??'
            });
    }]);
```

My only problem is that I can't figure out what I should put as the template URLs since I can't seem to access the files from a URL in any way.

Any ideas how to make this work? Or better yet, some best practices around the issue

Comment: The template URL needs to be a public URL containing the HTML template. It seems like overkill to have Rails process the template first, then have Angular have at it. Are you sure you can't simply serve simple, static templates instead of going through erb?

Comment: Now that you mention it, it does sound like overkill. Do you have another suggestion for how to do it that way (but still stay organized)?

Comment: I haven't used Rails in many years, which is why I'm commenting instead of answering :) In my Angular app, I just serve up my templates using a static router. The same handler that serves up my css, js, etc. Alternately, you can embed the templates into your main index html file, like this: https://gist.github.com/vojtajina/3354046

Comment: really like the idea of embedding templates, didnt know I could do that with angular. Thank you!